# PHP scheduled task without Cron

Tags: php, server, scheduled-tasks

I have shared hosting with limited privileges to make advanced setup. But I need to make some job once a time without Cron. So how can I run PHP script at scheduled time? Let's say I need to send email notification from server after 2h. My first idea to make loop until time is up, but wouldn't it drain resources unnecessarily? Second just compare server system time with desired time, but has nothing to run the script.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: There are also web cron services.

Comment: Also, your hosting provider is pretty cheap (as in low quality) for not offering a cron service. This is no longer a luxury. I do not know a single shared hosting service that doesn't offer cron. Just throw a stone in any direction and you will find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP `sleep` function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

You could potentially have a loop that would compare the current time to your desired time. If the current time still wasn't your desired time, you could sleep for x number of seconds.

*Word of caution: This method likely won't get your script to run at **exactly** your desired time like a cron job, but will be accurate to the amount of time you put in your sleep call in-between checks. Also, I wouldn't trust the sleep function to return at exactly your desired time (ex. if you want to wait five minutes then `sleep(5*60)` likely wouldn't return at exactly 5 minutes. Cron jobs would definitely be recommended if possible. *

Comment: OP could also use [time_sleep_until](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php), but I suspect no amount of set_time_limit(0) will allow more then a few seconds on shared hosting.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  time_sleep_until, it could work, Thanks. Sleep function just freeze process running on server? I ask because I want to know if sleep function lower server load instead of blank loop, probably yes :D